# sql select records that don't have relation in a third table

Tags: oracle

I have three tables

CLAIMS_TB

[image]

CLAIMS_RISK_TB

[image]

VEHICLE_TB

[image]

And then I need this result below:

[image]

Who can help me or share with me the query to be used?
N.B: If the code is 700 it means that it is a vehicle and it must fill the column called "ai_vehicle_use" otherwise it must leave it blank because "VEHICLE_TB" table contains only vehicles

This is what I tried:

```
   select 
klm.CM_PL_INDEX,
klm.cm_no,
klmrisk.cr_risk_code,
CASE WHEN klm.CM_PR_CODE = '0700' THEN klmrisk.cr_risk_code ELSE '' END,
 veh.ai_vehicle_use  
from  CLAIMS_TB klm 
JOIN CLAIMS_RISK_TB klmrisk 
  ON (klm.cm_index = klmrisk.cr_cm_index)  
INNER JOIN VEHICLE_TB veh 
  on veh.ai_regn_no = klm.cm_no  
where klm.cm_no='CL/01/044/00001/01/2018' 
or klmrisk.cr_cm_index='86594' 
order by klmrisk.cr_risk_code;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server ? Dont tag multiple RDBMS. All are different!

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I advice you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section  "Help others reproduce the problem".. Images does not help us to reprodure..

Comment: show us what querry you wrote so far?

Comment: select klm.CM_PL_INDEX, klm.cm_no, klmrisk.cr_risk_code,
 CASE 
 WHEN klm.CM_PR_CODE = '0700' THEN  klmrisk.cr_risk_code ELSE '' 
 END,
  veh.ai_vehicle_use
 from CLAIMS_TB klm JOIN  CLAIMS_RISK_TB klmrisk ON (klm.cm_index = klmrisk.cr_cm_index)
 INNER JOIN VEHICLE_TB veh on veh.ai_regn_no = klm.cm_no
 where 
klm.cm_no='CL/01/044/00001/01/2018'
or
 klmrisk.cr_cm_index='86594' 
order by  klmrisk.cr_risk_code;

This is the query that I tried

Comment: Instead of comments could you add your attempt to the question? Formatting of comments is horrible for code. Also instead of images it would be helpful to post text. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). And there is a great article [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to demonstrate what you should post to make it easy for others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could fit your needs.

```
SELECT
*
FROM CLAIMS_TB AS c
LEFT JOIN CLAIMS_RISK_TB cl ON c.cm_index = cl.cr_cm_index
LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_TB v ON cl.cr_risk_code = v.ai_risk_index
```

Comment: it refuses, i think it because VEHICLE_TB contains only vehicles (700)

Comment: @Isaackitenge - do you mean this query doesn't run? If so please post error message. If it returns the wrong results please explain how the results are wrong. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help us get you the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I find the solution, query below works:

```
select * from CLAIMS_TB  c
JOIN CLAIMS_RISK_TB cr ON( C.CM_INDEX = cr.cr_cm_index) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VEHICLE_TB v ON (cr.cr_risk_code = v.ai_regn_no);
```